# Side Scrolling text from a user scrolling action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im coding an application in react how can I trigger side-scrolling text from a user’s scrolling action?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use the `onScroll` event to detect when the user is scrolling and then update the position of your text accordingly.